# Julia instantiation concept

Tags: julia

I have been reading the Julia Documentation, and also some blogs on the internet, and I have found sentences that mention the concept of instantiation, for instance, "Int64 can be instantiated". I found some information on this concept here:

https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/instantiation.htm

but I cannot see how this could be used in Julia or why it is relevant. Any comment would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This coul also help: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-jargon-terminology-definitions-please-check/75234 And more in details [this](https://sylvaticus.github.io/IntroSPMLJuliaCourse/dev/01_-_JULIA1_-_Basic_Julia_programming/0102-types_and_objects.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say that type can be instantiated if it is possible to create an object that has this type.

For example `Int64` can be instantiated as e.g. `1` on a 64-bit machine by default has this type:

```
julia> typeof(1)
Int64
```

However, a supertype of `Int64` is `Signed`:

```
julia> supertype(Int64)
Signed
```

The `Signed` type cannot be instantiated, because it is abstract (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-abstract-types). This means that it is impossible to create an object that has type `Signed`.